# How do i get a device token of my computer?

Tags: java, push-notification, token, devicetoken

I am trying to create a small application that will read the CPU load of computers / laptops and send a push notification to the browser of my main laptop, which will contain the user name and how much the processor is loaded. As a technology for sending notifications, I chose FCM. The code itself is already ready, but I lack one detail. I need to get the device token of my laptop, to which this push notification will be sent (because as I understand it, the device token is the token of the computer where the notification is sent). But I do not know how to get this token. Most of the guidelines are directed to Android, and I need to send it from computer to computer. Maybe someone can tell me a different approach to sending these notifications, or the option that I attached is also suitable for a start? If so, how can I get this token?

```
public class MetricTesting {      
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("typeperf \"\\238(_Total)\\6\"");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    double pr = 0;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\d]{0,3}\\.\\d{4,}");
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(line);
        if (!m.find()) {
            continue;
        }
        line = m.group();
        pr = Math.round(Double.parseDouble(line) * 10.0) / 10.0;
        System.out.println(pr);
        if (pr > 5) {
            PushNotificationSender.sendPushNotification("??", Double.toString(pr));   
            System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.name") + ", Processor loaded " + pr + " %");

        }

    }
    String[] g = br.readLine().split("");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(g));
    br.close();
}

}




  class PushNotificationSender {

public final static String AUTH_KEY_FCM = "//";
public final static String API_URL_FCM = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

public static String sendPushNotification(String deviceToken, String pr)
        throws IOException, JSONException {
    String result = "";
    URL url = new URL(API_URL_FCM);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + AUTH_KEY_FCM);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    json.put("to", deviceToken.trim());
    JSONObject info = new JSONObject();
    info.put("title", "CPU is overloaded"); 
    info.put("body", System.getProperty("user.name")+"\n"+pr);
    json.put("notification", info);
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(json.toString());
        wr.flush();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }
        result = "OK";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        result = "BAD";
    }

    return result;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must try https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client to create a web client for firebase push notification.
In the above article, generating firebase token is also mentioned.
You can try to push notification thru topic instead of firebase token as well.